# Shell script: for-loop within while loop

Tags: shell

I have 32 files (named by the same pattern, the only difference is the $sample number as written below) that I want to divide into 4 folders. I am trying to use the following script to do this job, but the script is not working, can someone help me with the following shell script please? - Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

max=8    #8 files in each sub folder
numberFolder=4
sample=0

while ($numberFolder > 1) #skip the current folder, as 8 files will remain
do
  for (i=1; i<9; i++)
  do
   $sample= $i * $numberFolder   # this distinguish one sample file from another
   echo "tophat_"$sample"_ACTTGA_L003_R1_001"  //just an echo test, if works, will replace it with "cp".

  done
$numberFolder--
end
```

Comment: `while (( numberFolder > 1 ))` must be written _exactly_ that way, with the double `(( ))`. Same thing for the `for` loop.

Comment: You need math context in other places too: `(( sample = i * numberFolder ))`, `(( numberFolder-- ))`. Notably, when you're in a math context, you _don't_ need to use `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use math contexts -- `(( ))` -- correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

max=8
numberFolder=4
sample=0

while (( numberFolder > 1 )); do # math operations need to be in a math context
  for ((i=1; i<9; i++)); do # two (( )), not ( ).
    (( sample = i * numberFolder ))
    echo "tophat_${sample}_ACTTGA_L003_R1_001" # don't unquote before the expansion
  done
  (( numberFolder-- )) # math operations need to be inside a math context
done
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, but your code hassyntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @user2228325 I copied (rather than correcting) the mistake of putting an `end` in place of the final `done`. Try that again.